# Csharp - Convert single to decimal without converting to a string

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I am getting a value from an OdcDataReader that comes across as a Single type. I do not want to work with a single in code and so I want to convert it into a decimal. However, it seems that anytime I try to cast it to a decimal (or anything for that matter) it loses several decimal places. I need to keep as much accuracy as possible for my calculations. The only way I could find is to convert the single to a string with a 'R' parameter (Round Trip) and then parse the string into a decimal. I created some Extension Methods to convert them but I was hoping there was a way to convert them without the string conversion and parsing. Keep in mind I need to keep the precision.

```
Single sng = 1.32397970f;       // 1.32397974
decimal d = (decimal)sng;       // 1.32398M
d = Convert.ToDecimal(sng);     // 1.32398M
string xxx = sng.ToString("G"); // "1.32398"
xxx = sng.ToString("C");        // "$1.32"
xxx = sng.ToString("E");        // "1.323980E+000"
xxx = sng.ToString("e");        // "1.323980e+000"
xxx = sng.ToString("F");        // "1.32"
xxx = sng.ToString("G");        // "1.32398"
xxx = sng.ToString("N");        // "1.32"
xxx = sng.ToString("P");        // "132.40 %"
xxx = sng.ToString("R");        // "1.32397974" - Bingo!

// My extension methods
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static decimal ToDecimal(this Single value)
    {
        decimal d = decimal.Parse(value.ToString("R"));
        return d;
    }

    public static decimal ToDecimal(this Single? value, decimal dflt)
    {
        if (!value.HasValue)
            return dflt;

        decimal d = decimal.Parse(value.Value.ToString("R"));
        return d;
    }

    public static decimal? ToDecimal(this Single? value)
    {
        if (!value.HasValue)
            return null;

        decimal d = decimal.Parse(value.Value.ToString("R"));
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're losing the precision by starting with a Single to begin with. Decimals actually have twice the precision of doubles (and so four times the precision of singles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following will satisfy your criteria, even though I find it strange to use a Single for a currency value.  The method has successfully round tripped the value based on limited testing.  The technique is based on limiting the maximum number of significant digits to 9 as that is the maximum possible for IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point value.

```
Single sng = 1.32397970f;
Decimal dec = SingleToDecimal(sng);
Single sng2 = Convert.ToSingle(dec);
bool b = sng.Equals(sng2);
```

---

```
 private static decimal SingleToDecimal(float s)
 {
    // From: IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point format: binary32
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32

    // The IEEE 754 standard specifies a binary32 as having:

    //    Sign bit: 1 bit
    //    Exponent width: 8 bits
    //    Significand precision: 24 bits (23 explicitly stored)

    //This gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision
    const int maxSignificantDigits = 9;

    decimal sign = (s < 0F) ? decimal.MinusOne : decimal.One;
    s = Math.Abs(s);

    double whole = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Floor(s));
    double fraction = s - whole;

    int roundOffDigits = 0;
    if (whole > 0)
    {
        int numDigitsInWhole = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(whole))) + 1;
        roundOffDigits = maxSignificantDigits - numDigitsInWhole;
    }
    else
    {
        int numLeadZerosInFraction = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(-Math.Log10(fraction)));
        roundOffDigits = maxSignificantDigits + numLeadZerosInFraction;
    }

    fraction = Math.Round(fraction, roundOffDigits, MidpointRounding.ToEven);

    return new decimal(fraction + whole) * sign;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks TnTinMn. Yeah it is weird but the problem is that our database is a very old version of Informix, running on an AIX machine and we are accessing it from windows machines running .NET using Odbc drivers. The OdbcDataReader at some point decides the data type is Single, even though Informix thinks the field is a decimal with no scale defined.

Answer (score 2):

Convert it do a double first, then to a decimal and you will get more "precision".

```
decimal d = (decimal)Convert.ToDouble(sng);
```

You will get more precision than is actually in the single value to begin with, though.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I can use the number though, its too much precision:1.32397973537445M. I was hoping to just get the number as it is. I won't know how how far to round it.

Comment: Best way to use it as-is, is to stick with Single.  Much faster than decimal anyway since it has native machine support on most processors, whereas decimal type does not.

Comment: It's a price and doubles and singles don't play well with money when you do a lot of multiplying and dividing. You get very unpredictable results unless you constantly round them.

Comment: Indeed.  Have you tried rounding it to the precision you do want?  e.g. ` decimal d = Math.Round((decimal)Convert.ToDouble(sng), 7);`

Comment: That would be ideal IF we had a set number of places for the price. Unfortunately it could be any number of places (it's a floating point value in the DB), so unless I examined the original value (like turning it into a string and seeing how many characters were to the left of the decimal point) I don't know how many places to round the converted value. At least I can't think of a way off hand.

Comment: That means you've already lost the precision in the database.  No way to know how many of the last 2 digits or so of that single value were meant to be there.

Comment: I've run some pretty extensive tests (writing and reading from the database) and the values seem to come back 'true' to what I put in. It's an old Informix DB, I'm sure I would not have this trouble with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You could do folowing:

```
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal((double)sng);
```

that will give you result of :

> 1,32397973537445

Comment: Thank you, it's a good answer but I won't be able to use the result due to too much precision. I don't know how many decimal places the number will have and so I won't know how far to round it. It's a price and so may be multiplied by a very large number and the extra precision will cause problems.